# jQuery nth child of a span in a list from event parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, event-handling

I would like to get the text() values of every span. Best case scenario would involve a solution that makes use of the "event"-parameter.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
      console.log($("span:nth-of-type(1n)").text());
      console.log($("span:nth-of-type(2n)").text());
      console.log($("span:nth-of-type(3n)").text());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>li1 + span1</span>
      <span>li1 + span2</span>
      <span>li1 + span3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>li2 + span1</span>
      <span>li2 + span2</span>
      <span>li3 + span3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you have any idea, I would highly appreciate a working snippet.

The expected output would be something like:

```
let var1 = $("span:nth-of-type(1n)").text(); // li1 + span1
let var2 = $("span:nth-of-type(2n)").text(); // li1 + span2
let var3 = $("span:nth-of-type(3n)").text(); // li1 + span3
```

In the forEach-loop solution, I would need the span's text element in every loop, which I don't have.

Comment: Your code seems to be working. Do you have an issue with it? What output are you expecting to have?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Not really, note the first `console.log` output.

Comment: That's because it's getting the text of every `1n` span. I get that it may not be what the OP wants, but they haven't specified what they *do* want. I didn't downvote you FYI

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would assume they have more than three span tags or a variable number. I think they just want to display the text from each span separately

Comment: It is not really a duplicate per se, since I am not looking for a solution involving a forEach loop to print all the results inside the console, but rather assign each span's text() value to a local variable. Could anybody assist please?

Answer (score 3):

> Best case scenario would involve a solution that makes use of the "event"-parameter

You *can* do that, but there's no need to; `this` within the `click` callback will be the `li` element on which the event was hooked. (But see the second snippet below if you really want to use the event parameter.)

So we can loop through the spans within the `li`, either using `$(this).find("span")` (all descendants) or `$(this).children("span")` (just direct children):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
      $(this).children('span').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>li1 + span1</span>
      <span>li1 + span2</span>
      <span>li1 + span3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>li2 + span1</span>
      <span>li2 + span2</span>
      <span>li3 + span3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If using the event parameter is really important, we can use `e.currentTarget` to get the same thing `this` gives us in the above:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
      $(e.currentTarget).children('span').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
      });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>li1 + span1</span>
      <span>li1 + span2</span>
      <span>li1 + span3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>li2 + span1</span>
      <span>li2 + span2</span>
      <span>li3 + span3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I find useful. I made the same answer and before posting I found your answer. +1

Comment: Yeah, not really sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: Same on my answer, it exactly fits the requirement but get downvoted ... love this community <3

Comment: @mr.void you just copied the code OP posted.

Comment: Perhaps the issue was not using the event parameter. I *did* fail to address that originally, so I've added that now.

Comment: @George ... better look twice ... there is an $(this)

Comment: @George: No, there's a crucial difference between mr.void's and the OP's: Using `$(this)` rather than searching globally.

Comment: I am not looking for a solution involving a forEach loop to print all the results inside the console, but rather assign each span's text() value to a local variable. Could anybody assist please?

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/g998f2hv/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').click(function (e) {
      var spans = $(this).find("span");
      console.log($(spans[0]).text());
      console.log($(spans[1]).text());
      console.log($(spans[2]).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah downvote more... for all who says that wont work or return an empty string here an WORKING FIDDLE... BUT YEAH DOWNVOTE MORE PLS
https://jsfiddle.net/g998f2hv/

Comment: li1 + span1li1 + span2li1 + span3
li1 + span2
li1 + span3

This is not the output wanted and actually the same output I have in my initial post.

Comment: Ah okay i got it, i updated my answer

Comment: That fiddle is not working unfortunately.